# Скрипт "Мне нравится"

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Проблема следующая.

http://soft.yshi.ru/123456.html

Скрипт Вконтакте "Мне нравится" работает вот на этом скрипте openapi.js.
Я его скачал себе на хост, ну и прописал в html'ке путь у себя на серваке (http://soft.yshi.ru/openapi.js). Скрипт прекрасно работает.

При загрузке страницы он генерит hash код для выполнения дальнейших действий (при условии, что юзер ранее авторизован Вконтакте).

Сначала срабатывает функция `VK.Init`, `VK.Util`, затем `VK.Widgets.Like`, 
для выполнения `VK.Widgets.Like` требуется вот этот самый hash, в js файле он обозван как `VK._session.sid`.

Внимание вопрос: "Как его можно вывести (пробую править openapi.js, получается, но в javascript я мало что пока понимаю), ну, к примеру, в alert и где его получить вообще. Место, где он генерится и из чего, в js файле я нашел, что дальше?

идея такова, если получится это сделать, то можно будет идентифицировать/логировать почти всех пользователей посетителей сайта без их ведома(), при условии что посетитель авторизован вконтакте, а это 95% всех пользователей

Comment: Вообщем это типа счетчика, я так понимаю?

Comment: Ну так собственно можно просто сделать авторизацию через OAuth вконтакте и вы получите основную инфу пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Данные из фрейма, который находится на другом домене, получить нельзя, если этот фрейм не предоставляет никакого апи (`urlhash, postMessage`) для этого, т.е. в случае вконтакта хэш получить не получится.